# Html.Actionlink as Button effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make look @Html.Actionlink as button.

**Working  Html.Actionlink:**

```
 <li class="btn btn-sm"> @Html.ActionLink("Redeem Reward", "GetReward",
 "Home", new { id = price.PriceId }, new { @class = "lnkGetReward"})</li>
```

Currently when I click it looks like as if a link is clicked, apart from the text if we click the button border it doesn't work.

I am also using font awesome classes.

Can I use `@Url.Action` instead with same `id` and `@class`?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Ashley, yes i use both bootstrap and font awesome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of having your button classes on the `li` apply them directly to the link.

As you are using bootstrap you might want to add `btn-default` to get the full style of the button.

```
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Redeem Reward", "GetReward", "Home", 
    new { id = price.PriceId }, 
    new { @class = "lnkGetReward btn btn-default btn-sm"})
</li>
```

However if you are 100% sure you want to use `Url.Action` your code would look like the following.

```
<li class="btn btn-sm">
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetReward", "Home", new { id = price.PriceId })" class="lnkGetReward">Redeem Reward</a>
</li>
```

Again I would suggest that you apply the `btn btn-sm` directly to the link. Possibly with a `btn-default`.

Edit based on comment:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetReward", "Home", new { id = price.PriceId })" class="lnkGetReward btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Redeem Reward
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you so much works fine, but UrlAction is not working on click , to make it clear i am using lnkGetReward in jquery on click.

Comment: secondly , can i add this icon: <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> with working @Html.ActionLink

Comment: No you will not be able to add HTML markup to the Text of an actionlink, See updated code at the end of the answer.

Comment: thank you so much, @Url.Action works great, appreciate your effort.